# Is it possible to use the built in device application camera in react native (expo)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, camera, expo

Currently we are using [expo camera](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/), we have to use our own buttons to take picture. I already saw android applications that were using my built in camera application. Is it possible to achieve that in react native with expo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the expo https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/. With it you can either use library to pick a picture or use the built in camera application. 
Look at the function [ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickerlaunchcameraasyncoptions)